# How to create a personal wiki+blog on github using org-mode?

Tags: github, blogs, wiki, org-mode, mathjax

I Love org-mode! I tried to create my personal pages using org-export-html. Org-mode can export latex-math using mathjax very well, and many many other feathers. I love that! I want a tidy and beautiful personal site integrated with wiki and blogs hosting on github.

How to configure org-mode to build such a wiki+blog site with theme support?

Comment: I have the same pending project.

Sacha Chua, one of my favorite orgmode power-user, asked recently on her blog "Do you have an Emacs-based personal wiki? What do you use, and what do you think about it?": you might be interested in the comment on her post:
http://sachachua.com/blog/2011/11/planning-an-emacs-based-personal-wiki-org-muse-hmm/

Comment: Thanks! I read it before. I want an easy start example. I will try re-configure my org-mode export when at large.

Comment: Have you looked at http://orgmode.org/worg/org-blog-wiki.html and http://orgmode.org/worg/org-web.html ?

Comment: Most of them on worg are based on ruby or obsolete. I will try to study the `org-publish` method again. Anyway, I can publish HTMLs, thought the style is not so beautiful. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think, this project fits my need:

1. http://renard.github.com/o-blog/
2. https://github.com/renard/o-blog

Comment: o-blog does not support separate org file for generating

Comment: That's why I switch to the plain `org-publish` now. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understood correctly your question, because I think there is nothing to do!

The wiki sites of git-hub have their own git repository.
Do a git checkout and add files edited in orgmode.
When you will commit and pull them, they will be output correctly in html.

(That's what I did for the project repositorium in git-hub)

Hope it helps,
Jeremy

Comment: Thanks. I know that. Maybe my question can be changed to: how to easily configure org-mode to build a wiki+blog site with better theme support.